# How to get raw XML sections from a serialized response message in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a XML response returned from a .NET Web Service. The API being used for the return response is a serialized response and it's stripping out the supplemental section of the XML since it's not part of the serialized class stack which I cannot change in the API. Is there a way get the raw XML response so I can get the supplemental:supplementalData section of my response message being returned or somehow just get the supplemental:supplementalData XML section it self?

Service API call is TestPort.TestPortType response = service.GetTestPortList() and the returned response doesn't contain the supplemental section since it's not part of the TestPort.TestResponse stack.

This is the Raw XML message returned via the Fiddle Analyzer:

```
    <TestResponse xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-filing:schema:xsd:TestResponse-4.0" xmlns:org="urn:org:ecf:extensions:Common" xmlns:j="http://niem.tech/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.tech/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.tech/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-filing:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <ecf:Error>
            <ecf:ErrorCode>0</ecf:ErrorCode>
            <ecf:ErrorText>No Error</ecf:ErrorText>
          </ecf:Error>
          <supplemental:supplementalData xmlns:supplemental="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-filing:schema:xsd:supplementalData-4.0">
            <nc:TestID>DATest159647</nc:TestID>
          </supplemental:supplementalData>
    </TestResponse>
```

This is the XML message returned from the API which is a serialized response, so since the supplemental:supplementalData section is not part of the serialized response it's ignored.

```
    <TestResponse xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-filing:schema:xsd:TestResponse-4.0" xmlns:org="urn:org:ecf:extensions:Common" xmlns:j="http://niem.tech/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.tech/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.tech/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-filing:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <ecf:Error>
            <ecf:ErrorCode>0</ecf:ErrorCode>
            <ecf:ErrorText>No Error</ecf:ErrorText>
          </ecf:Error>
    </TestResponse>
```

This is the XML section I'm trying to get access to from within my .Net hosting app after the response is returned, but it's being stripped out of the returned serialized response.

```
    <supplemental:supplementalData xmlns:supplemental="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-filing:schema:xsd:supplementalData-4.0">
            <nc:TestID>DATest159647</nc:TestID>
    </supplemental:supplementalData>
```

Comment: Is the web service WCF? If it is WCF, you can intercept the message through IDispatchMessageInspector to get the original XML part.For more information about IDispatchMessageInspector,Please refer to the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes the Web Service is a WCF service and I'm hosting a WCF service. On my side and the service host part is the one calling API method. Can I use the IDispatchMessageInspector in the hosted console part of the service or does that only work in the service side of the app itself. Is the IDispatchMessageInspector easy to implement to get the raw xml response only?

Comment: How would I wrap the IDispatchMessageInspector around the API calling method to get the xml response?

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq.  I read a string from a file.  You can use similar code to get the response string and create an xdocument.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement supplementalData = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "supplementalData").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace supplemental = supplementalData.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("supplemental");
            XNamespace nc = supplementalData.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("nc");

            string TestID = (string)supplementalData.Element(nc + "TestID");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, My .Net app is calling an API method like this TestPort.TestPortType response = service.GetTestPortList(). The TestPort.TestPortType is a serialized class and it's stripping off the supplemental:supplementalData section of the XML response because it not part of the serialized TestPort.TestPortType class. Somehow, I need access to the supplemental:supplementalData section.

Comment: How were the classes generated?  XML Serialization only deserializer properties that are in the classes.  So there is something wrong with your classes. Usually there is a schema that is used to build the classes.  Your classes may have been built with an older version of version of the schema and you classes need to be updated.  Or the xml you are getting is bad and doesn't meed the schema requirements.  The supplemental section of the xml may need a different schema and you classes were built to the supplemental schema.

Comment: Is missing section shown on following : http://docs.oasis-open.org/legalxml-courtfiling/specs/ecf/v4.0/ecf-v4.0-spec/ecf-v4.0-spec.html

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the API WSDL provided to us has the serialized classes for the TestResponse message, but unfortunately, it doesn't include serialization for the supplemental:supplementalData section that is embedded in the message that I need and when the serialized response is returned it doesn't get loaded. So I need to gain access to raw XML section some how.

Comment: Do you have the URL?  Do you need the API?  You can connect directly to the URL in c#.

Answer (score 0):

If the server-side intercepts the SOAP message,it needs to implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface.

```
public class ServerMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(request);
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reply);
        }
    }
```

Request is the SOAP message received by the server-side from the client-side.
If the client-side intercepts the SOAP message,it needs to implement the IClientMessageInspector interface.

```
 public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reply);
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(request);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

We need to add the class that implements IDispatchMessageInspector or IClientMessageInspector to the behavior of the server-side or the client-side.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute,IOperationBehavior
    {
        public Type TargetContract => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageLogger());
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Finally,we need to apply this behavior to the service.

```
    [CustContractBehavior]
    public interface IService1
    {...
```